# Tkinter + Led. Как включить светодиод нажатием на кнопку виджета?

Tags: linux, tkinter

Реализовать следующую задачу для любого ноутбука или стат.компьютера:

1. Посредством библиотеки Tkinter создать виджет с одной кнопкой
2. Связать событие кнопки с передачей единицы по USB
3. Зажечь светодиод

Что уже есть

1. Понимание работы библиотеки Tkinter
2. Знания в работе с микроконтроллерами stm32 (не понятно, надо ли вообще)

К сожалению, есть полное непонимание того, как связать нажатие кнопки с загоранием светодиода на любом компьютере. Что здесь нужно сделать? Порт какой-то задействовать? Свисток на USB спаять? Это какойто-конвертер?

Данная задача реализована, но с использованием Raspberry Pi. Малинка заточена для работы с такими игрушками. В ней уже реализовано готовое ПО. Это всё не то.

Как этот трюк повторить на обычном железе? Какова последовательность действий?

Подскажите советом, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - это использовать относительно готовое железо, например - конвертеры USB-Serial FT232 и CP210X.

По крайней мере, вам не придется писать прошивку и использовать библиотеки, так как эти железяки управляются стандартным API операционной системы.

У порта RS232, который реализуют через USB данные микросхемы, помимо основных линий передачи данных TX/RX есть вспомогательные, в частности, линия RTS.

[image: FT232]
Для управления этой линией,  [имеется функция WinApi](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-escapecommfunction)

```
BOOL EscapeCommFunction(
  HANDLE hFile,
  DWORD  dwFunc
);
```

Включить линию:  `EscapeCommFunction(hComm, SETRTS);`

Выключить линию: `EscapeCommFunction(hComm, CLRRTS);`

[Пример исходника](https://github.com/xanthium-enterprises/DTR-RTS-Pin-Control-using-Win32-API-C/blob/master/RTS_Ctrl_Win32.c)

Comment: А есть аналог этой функции для Linux?

Comment: Да, есть полный аналог. Кроме того, оба чипа имеют свои библиотеки, которые позволяют дергать произвольным образом аж восемью линиями - они становятся GPIO